# NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Relation RSpec Configuration Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to run a suite of tests that I have migrated from Minitest to Rspec. While trying to run a controller spec, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while loading rails_helper.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

NameError:
  uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Relation
# /var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `block in load_missing_constant'
# /var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
```

Here are the relevant files:

spec/controllers/cdns_controller_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe CdnsController, type: :controller do


  let(:cdn) { cdns :one }

  it "gets index" do
    get :index
    value(response).must_be :success?
    value(assigns(:cdns)).wont_be :nil?
  end
end
```

Here is my rails-helper.rb. It is pretty standard.

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails' do
add_filter '/bin/'
 add_filter '/db/'
 add_filter '/test/'
 add_filter '/config/'
 add_group "Models", "app/models"
 add_group "Controllers", "app/controllers"
 add_group "Helpers", "app/helpers"
 add_group "Lib", "lib/"
end

# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'support/factory_bot'
require 'database_cleaner'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#

Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove these lines.

begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end

end
```

Here is my spec_helper.rb. It is also pretty standard.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|

    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end


  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|

    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end


   config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
end
```

And finally here is my .rspec

```
--require rails_helper
```

I'd like to point out that this all started with the below error:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::CdnsController:0x0000000000ed87d0>
```

To fix the 'get' error, I tried to change my `.rspec` contents from `require spec_helper` to `require rails_helper`. That fix triggered the ActiveRecord:Relation error. Since then, I've tried to play with RSpec for inferring controller specs option, explicitly specifying `type: :controller`, then removing it and I'm getting nowwhere I'm hoping that someone could help me pinpoint what is wrong. I can tell that something is not loading correctly and could use some help. If more information is needed, I will gladly provide it. Thanks.

Comment: The configuration files where split many years ago into `spec_helper.rb` and `rails_helper.rb`.  `spec_helper.rb` only contains the bare minimum to run RSpec itself and you can require it if you have tests for things that don't require the rails stack. I would recommend explicit `require 'rails_helper'` statements using over implicitly using `.rspec` as that does not allow you to choose per file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply max, but your comment opens up a lot of questions. One of which is this: I just deleted everything and ran a generator. The rails_helper has the `require spec_helper` in it. And my new controller spec has `require rails_helper` on top of the file from the generator. So every spec is using rails_helper and requiring spec_helper. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes correct. You could say that `rails_helper.rb` extends `spec_helper.rb` by loading the Rails stack and RSpec rails. If you have configured `require rails_helper` in `.rspec` all your specs will use `rails_helper.rb`  which is fine but it means that you can't run specs for plain old ruby objects without loading the rails stack which is slower when running those specs individually.